# python pandas dataframe manipulation. Stripping multi-dimension dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, import-from-csv

I am trying to strip off a 2nd-dimension dataframe and save all the data as a single dimension dataframe.
For example,

Original df:

```
[[v1, v2, v3, v4]]
```

How I want it to be:

```
[v1, v2, v3, v4]
```

I searched for a solution but naming this question was too vague, I could not find any. Please help

---

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

os.listdir()
List = os.listdir('E:/Programming/Alpha_Vantage/300DayPortfolio/Price')
List2 = []

for i in range(len(List)):
    List[i] = List[i].strip('.csv')
for i in range(300):
    List2.append(i)

#Loading Stock Price Data
DF = pd.DataFrame(columns = [List], index=[List2])
print(DF)

for i in range(len(List)):
    print("processing ", i, "th file")
    DF.loc[str(List[i])] = pd.read_csv('E:/Programming/Alpha_Vantage/300DayPortfolio/Price/' + str(List[i]) + '.csv')
```

So this is my code. I am trying to get stock price data from .csv files and save them all together in a pandas dataframe. So far, I think the problem I am facing here is because .csv file are not formatted ideally. In fact they look like this in a file.

['12.3700', '12.2500', '12.2000', '12.2000', '12.2100', '12.2000', '12.0800', '12.0500', '12.1500', '12.2000', '12.2500', '12.3800', '12.2200', '12.1300', '12.1600', '12.1500', '12.0800', '12.1000', '12.1600', '12.1500', '12.2000', '12.2400', '12.2500', '12.3200', '12.3500', '12.3520', '12.3100', '12.1000', '12.1500', '12.1500', '12.2900', '12.3400', '12.3000', '12.2800', '12.2000', '12.2300', '12.2400', '12.1000', '12.2800', '12.3300', '12.2300', '12.2900', '12.1900', '12.3500', '12.3500', '12.4000', '12.4500', '12.2700', '12.5000', '12.3900', '12.4200', '12.4000', '12.4200', '12.4600', '12.4800', '12.5000', '12.4900', '12.5800', '12.4500', '12.5800', '12.5900', '12.6400', '12.6000', '12.6900', '12.7700', '12.8400', '12.8500', '12.7500', '12.7500', '12.8900', '12.7900', '12.7800', '12.9100', '12.9900', '13.1800', '13.3000', '13.0900', '13.1900', '13.2100', '12.9000', '13.0000', '13.1900', '13.0600', '12.9800', '12.7100', '12.8100', '12.8000', '12.4100', '12.7500', '12.8400', '12.8800', '12.8500', '12.8300', '12.8600', '12.7600', '12.8900', '12.9800', '12.9400', '13.0000', '13.0700', '13.3100', '13.2100', '13.2500', '12.9000', '12.9500', '12.8900', '12.9200', '12.8600', '12.2100', '12.0100', '12.5100', '12.3100', '12.2900', '11.8600', '11.4000', '11.4700', '11.7000', '11.8500', '12.0500', '12.2300', '12.3100', '12.3200', '12.2700', '12.1300', '11.9300', '11.7000', '11.6500', '11.7100', '11.8000', '11.8000', '11.9600', '12.1600', '12.4000', '12.5500', '12.5000', '12.4600', '12.5100', '12.5800', '12.6800', '12.5900', '12.6500', '12.5700', '12.5000', '11.8800', '12.1400', '12.1500', '12.2400', '12.8100', '12.4000', '12.1800', '12.3000', '12.4600', '12.4500', '12.4100', '12.4500', '12.6200', '12.5100', '12.5900', '12.5000', '12.4000', '12.2500', '12.3400', '12.2600', '12.1300', '12.2000', '12.0300', '11.8800', '12.0300', '11.9000', '12.1600', '12.3300', '12.2700', '12.3200', '12.2900', '12.5200', '12.7600', '12.7200', '12.8800', '12.6800', '12.8900', '12.9000', '12.9000', '12.5800', '12.5100', '12.5100', '12.6000', '12.4600', '12.5000', '12.6000', '12.6200', '12.5400', '12.6400', '12.9600', '13.2500', '13.2200', '13.3000', '13.3400', '13.5700', '13.6400', '13.4300', '13.2600', '13.5600', '13.8600', '14.0000', '13.7000', '13.8500', '13.9800', '13.7800', '13.8600', '13.8600', '13.9500', '14.0000', '14.3300', '14.1600', '14.0300', '14.0200', '14.3900', '14.1100', '14.3100', '14.2600', '14.3400', '14.4600', '14.0800', '14.1600', '13.8900', '13.8500', '13.9900', '14.2100', '14.1200', '14.0300', '13.9400', '14.2800', '14.4700', '14.2600', '14.4200', '14.4200', '14.2100', '14.4000', '13.5100', '13.5000', '13.5400', '13.6000', '13.5000', '13.4600', '13.4300', '13.4500', '13.3000', '13.2100', '13.2000', '13.2400', '13.2000', '13.2100', '13.1900', '13.1700', '13.1500', '13.1500', '13.2500', '13.3200', '13.3000', '13.4000', '13.2600', '13.4500', '13.4500', '13.4000', '13.4700', '13.5700', '13.6700', '13.4200', '13.2500', '13.5000', '13.1600', '13.4100', '13.4600', '13.3000', '13.4500', '13.5300', '13.4100', '13.5000', '13.3400', '13.0600', '12.7400', '12.4500', '12.5000', '12.4500', '12.4300', '12.1600', '12.0600', '11.8700', '11.7400', '11.9600', '11.9500', '11.6000', '11.5500', '11.5500', '11.3200', '11.0300', '10.2500', '10.5600', '10.2000', '10.7100']

I think there should be no [] brackets in order to save these price data in a dataframe so I was asking if I could get rid of those brackets for all .csv files. Sorry for the late revision.

Comment: What do you mean by a 2nd-dimension dataframe, and a single dimension dataframe? 'Single dimension' sounds like you want a Series. Your shown examples are too short: consider using `df.head()` or similar to show more details about the dataframe.

Comment: `[[v1, v2, v3, v4]]` is not a DataFrame. It is a list or array the consists of a list or array of four elements.

Comment: `vs = [[a,b,c]][0]` ?

Comment: Your input file looks like a printed Python list, with all the numbers converting to strings as well. Not that that information will help you.

Comment: Without the brackets and single quotes (turning the strings into numbers), your CSV files still isn't a proper CSV file: I don't see any indication where a record stops (normally a newline), and there are no headers. You may want to sort out what the actual format of your data files is, and what you want to do with them: for example, should each data file correspond to one column in your dataframe?

Comment: It'll be a lot easier and quicker if you can find someone locally that knows Pandas and step through your code and what you're trying to do than a slow back and forth here on StackOverflow: there is just too much unclear.

Comment: Thanks I think it is a printed Python list. I should look into saving price files as a proper .csv file in the first place